# Converting site from wordpress to php/mysql without losing ranks and traffic?

Tags: php, wordpress, rank

I am using Wordpress script in my actual site, but I want to develop a new version using PHP/MySql.

Is there any way to preserve my site ranks and traffics in Google? For exemple if I rewrite the same article will they be reached as before by searchs in Google?

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing would change if you follow SEO guides properly which is additional burden on you now that you are writing your own code.

Comment: Thanks Kantu, and for the articles?

Comment: Picky note: even WP uses PHP/MySQL :) Apart from that, there's no SEO magic in CMSs, just follow the guidelines for better content and who cares in what language/framework/structure you code up the webiste. As for the articles, if you rewrite them they'll need to be reindexed I guess...why not just keeping them the same (rewrite just those you don't like?), and maybe provide a way for people coming from the "old" indexed content to still land to something useful (a nice 404 page, or to the new corresponing article)...but that's topic for another question, not this one

Comment: Just an FYI : You can log into WebDeveloper Google Account and you can ask Google to re index your site , this could be your last step after all rework

Comment: Yes sure WP uses PHP/MySQL :) Could you please explain more the point of articles?

Comment: Despite my answer I voted to close the question as _off topic_. It should be migrated to WPSE or Webmasters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress uses PHP/MySQL - Whatever modification you want to make to your site, I'm pretty sure you can write a WordPress plugin for that -

If you are making serious design changes, then your SEO ranks will drop for a while, I did it once for a client of mine and the pageranks took 4-8 weeks to come back up.

The same thing goes for permalink changes, it will take a while for the ranks to come back up - but it is also possible that it might never come back up.

By re-writing the articles if you meant, keeping the tags and keywords same and altering the content, then it will be treated as new content, but if it is too similar to the old article, it will regarded as duplicate content. If you are keeping the old article as is without changing the URL or front-end design, then your SEO will not be affected by changing the back-end CMS, but if you were using any sort of WordPress plugin for generating meta-data you might want to keep those.

Answer (score 0):

Search engines don’t care about the software you use. Make sure to keep the URIs (no 404s) and the proper markup. By the way: WordPress *is already* PHP and MySQL. ;)

Also I think your question doesn’t belong to Stack Overflow. If you want to write another CMS because you cannot do something with WordPress ask on [WordPress Stack Exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) first. They may show you an easier way to reach your goal.
If you have more detailed questions about SEO ask on [Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).